# Захардкодить адрес указателя в Си и инициализировать значение по данному указателю

Tags: c

Прохожу курс операционных систем и пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм страничной организации памяти.  В алгоритме есть ограниченное количество страниц (`NUMBER_PAGEBLE_PAGES = 33`) и структура `mem_map_t`, содержащая поле-указатель на первый элемент каждой страницы `uint32_t *page`.

Ниже приведен код, который, как предполагается, содержит локальный указатель, получающий адрес свободной страницы, и далее, начиная с полученного адреса, выполняет последовательную инициализацию всего адресного пространства данной страницы значением 0:

```
static uint32_t *allocate_page(void)

{

    uint32_t i = 0; 
    uint32_t j = 0;
    uint32_t *page = NULL;

    printf("here 2\n");
    while (i < NUM_PAGEABLE_PAGES) {
        if (m_map[i].in_use == 0) {
            m_map[i].in_use = 1;
            page = m_map[i].page;
            printf("here 3   %p\n", page);

            // Данная строка выдает segmentation fault 11 при инициализации ячейки памяти по указанному адресу. Почему?
            *page = 0;                     

            printf("here 4   %p\n", page);

            // данный "while-loop" пытается инициализировать все остальные ячейки в указанном
            while (j < 1024) {
                j++;
                printf("here 5\n");
                page[j] = 0;
                printf("here 6\n");
            }
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return page;
}


Вывод в терминале следующий $ ./a.out
here 2
here 3   0x100000
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Получается, что локальный указатель `uint32_t *page` получает начальное значение 0x100000, но при инициализации ячейки памяти по указанному адресу значением 0 выдает ошибку.

Может быть есть идеи в чем здесь дело?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ошибка к обращению чужой памяти. Адрес берётся здесь: `page = m_map[i].page;` Значит, там у Вас хранится не выделенная память или недостаточно выделенная. Точно ли её там выделяется 1025?? Вы ведь с индекса 1 начинаете цикл! Попробуйте итерации поставить после обращения к памяти, если так не было странно задумано. И не ставите j на ноль перед циклом. А это задумано?

Comment: @AivanF. Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка к обращению чужой памяти. Адрес берётся здесь: `page = m_map[i].page;` Отсюда возможные причины ошибки:

- Точно ли её там выделяется 1025? Вы ведь с индекса 1 начинаете обход массива, так как `j++;` стоит *до* обращения к памяти. Попробуйте поставить после, если так не было странно задумано. Кстати, такие числа лучше выносить в константы.
- Вы также не ставите значение `j` равным нулю перед циклом с `j` циклом. Это задумано? Если нет, то надо поправить.

Answer (score 4):

Как уже обозначалось в моем вопросе, работа ведется над курсом "*Операционные системы*", который предполагает разработку своей простенькой операционной системы с нуля, но в описании вопроса был упущен момент, что все (*в данном конкретном случае*) адресное пространство должно инициализироваться мануально (*вручную*), *без использования стандартных Си библиотек*. Конкретным заданием на данном этапе является написание алгоритма страничной организации оперативной памяти (***paging***).

Вы были правы. В приведенном программном коде, содержащем метод "**allocate_page()**", выскочила *ошибка при обращении к чужому адресному пространству*. Вопрос заключался в том, чтобы понять причину ее возникновения, так как в приведенном выше коде вроде бы задается адрес переменной "page = m_map[i].page", что в результате означает " *page =* **0x100000** ", и далее, начиная с данного адреса, не выделяя заранее памяти, начинается попытка инициализации ячеек памяти каждого последующего адреса, а именно "*0x100000, 0x100004, 0x100008, ... , 0x101000 (не включая последний)" значением "(uint32_t) 0*".

Ошибка, как оказалось, возникала из-за того, что выделение памяти с помощью библиотечных функций "**malloc()**" или "**calloc()**" в реализуемом проекте не предусматривается, а сегменты памяти, к которым в свою очередь производился запрос, оказывались занятыми другими процессами, запущенными на машине, на которой производилась компиляция кода. Реализуемый же проект предполагает *наличие абсолютно пустой оперативной памяти, которая делится на сегменты (страницы) в мануальном (ручном) режиме*, в определенном смысле приведенная в коде функция "**allocate_page()**" является неким самодельным прототипом "**malloc()**" ( или "**calloc()**" ). 
Поэтому в описанном в моем вопросе алгоритме после инициализации указателя " **page = m_map[i].page;** ", (что в результате дает *page =* **0x100000**), при обращении к области памяти по данному адресу выдавалась ошибка сегментации, так как данная область, как написано чуть выше, уже используется либо операционной системой, либо каким-то процессом в защищенном режиме на запускаемой данный код машине, а это значит, что доступ к выбранному сегменту адресного пространства запрещен.

При запуске в **терминале** код выдает ошибку сегментации, а в "**Bochs x86-64 emulator**" все сработало отлично, все инициализировалось как и предполагалось (имеется ввиду " *p[0] = 0, p[1] = 0, ... , p[1023] = 0* ").

Что же касается индекса "**j**" и началом "**while-loop**" с "**j = 1**", а не с "**j = 0**" это все были эксперименты, чтобы определить, где алгоритм инициализации адресов в адресном пространстве "*0x10000 - 0x101000*" "споткнется" и выдаст ошибку.

Спасибо за дискуссию и советы, все было интересно и по делу!